# JavaScript Pagination is Highlighting the Last Tab on the First Page

Tags: javascript, pagination

Thanks for any help - new coder here...

Having a problem regarding pagination (a news page that shows 20 posts per page - there are 5 pages in total that are navigated via table cells). The code below adds an active class (highlights the selected page number) to the current page you're on after class "news-pages-option" is selected. The default news page is accessed by selecting News on the top menu. The URL is www.website.com/news.

The problem: 
Going to the default news page (www.website.com/news) is highlighting the last number that is displayed on the page (see # 5 in the picture below). I would like the first number (1) to be highlighted when you go to www.website.com/news.

For reference, if the second page is selected (viewing posts 21-41), the URL changes to www.website.com/news?p=2 ("/news?p=3" is page 3's articles and so on).

[image: Image Example]

---

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<table class="news-pages" id="paginator">
  <tr>
    <% for(var i = 1; i <= num_pages; i++) { %>
      <td class="news-pages-option"><%-i%></td>
    <% } %>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

JS (to load # of pages):

```
  $('#paginator tr td').on('click', function(){
    var loc = window.location;
    window.location = `${loc.protocol + '//' + loc.host + loc.pathname}? 
    p=${$(this).html()}`;
  });

  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
      results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }

  const page = getParameterByName('p') - 1;
  $('.news-pages-option:eq(' + page + ')').addClass('active');
```

CSS:

```
.news-pages-option {
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

.news-pages-option:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.news-pages-option.active {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  text-decoration: underline;
 }

.news-pages-option.active:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  border: 2px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: Going to the default news page -- how are you going to default news page? Are you refreshing the page?

Comment: Hey @user1531038,  I get to the default news page via the top navigation menu.

Comment: This behavior is only when you are going to default page after navigating to 5th page or from any other page also? I mean if I navigate to page 3 and then to default page the highlighted page no is 3 or 5?

Comment: @user1531038 - great question, the highlighted page, in that case, is 5 (though it should be 1). There are two URLs. The default is www.website.com/news and viewing the 2, 3, 4, or 5th, page is www.website.com/news?p=2 or /news?p=3.

Comment: Not sure about this weird behavior.. Can try `if (!results) return '1';`  instead of `null`

Comment: @user1531038 - yup, that did it! Thank you, thank you!